# How to remove certain elements from an array into a new array and leave the no duplicate elements at the same position with the same array length

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i'm trying to do something like that :

```
1)-->take this array [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8]

2)-->this is the result [1,,2,,3,,4,,5,,6,,7,,8,,]
```

Sorry if i'm not show my own solution but literally i've really no idea how to resolve it.

**edit**

```
    let arr=[];
    let arr= [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8];
    arr.forEach(val=>{
    let previusVal=0;
    if(previusVal!==val){
     arr.push(val);
     }
});
console.log(arr)//wrong->x [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the previous element and if unequal assign the actual value the the actual index of the result array.

```js
var array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8],
    result = [];

array.forEach((v, i, { [i - 1]: p }) => {
    if (p !== v) result[i] = v;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: { [i - 1]: p } mean the previous?

Comment: right, it takes the array and destruture the previous element.

Comment: but when inside the array is added "undefined"   ---->`[1,,undefined2,,undefined,3,undefined,4,undefined,5,undefined,6,undefined,7,undefined,8]` this is equal to defin an array in this way -->`[1,,,3,,,4,,,5,,,6,,,7,,,8]`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the empty values are undefined, you can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for saving the first occurrence and [array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for creating the new array.

```js
const s = new Set();
const result = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8].map(i => !s.has(i) ? s.add(i) && i : undefined);

console.log(result);
```